# How to run DbMigration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration

I made some changes to my model that will get updated with automatic migrations,
but I have to execute manual migration first because pending automatic migrations can't 
execute before I apply my manual migration, so I can't use Update-Database.

Migration:

```
  public class Drop_Posts_IX_CategoryId : DbMigration 
    {
       public override void Up()
       {
           DropIndex("Posts", "IX_CategoryId");
       }
    }
```

So I run:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: Drop_Posts_IX_CategoryId
```

And I get:

```
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
The specified target migration 'Drop_Posts_IX_CategoryId' does not exist. Ensure that target migration refers to an existing migration id.
```